# Is there a name for adjectives like "beautiful", "incredible", "amazing", etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a name for adjectives like *beautiful*, *incredible*, *amazing*, etc.? Adjectives that are often generically substitutable when, say, describing vacation resorts, or the like. Preferably a name that doesn't sound salesperson-ey, but I'm curious to know those too, so do comment.

Comment: Meaningless? Boilerplate? Cliché? Marketese? Boring? Fluff? Insubstantial? Run-of-the-mill? Superfluous? Not really sure what you're after. (On a side note, arguably *all* adjectives in marketing are like that. Nobody would ever say, "our beer tastes bad", or "we use the unfinest ingredients", or "our rooms are cold and hideous".)

Comment: Fungible quasi-synonyms, hyperbolic tokens, hyper-hogwash, and baldfaced lies?

Comment: It's not clear what direction you're looking for. 'Generic', 'hyperbole', 'lies', 'euphemisms','subjective'. Something else? What general direction are you looking for? This needs more examples and context.

Comment: Apologies to everyone for responding so late! @Mitch - This was part of a tongue-in-cheek trip description, _"Walk ancient streets, travel through mountains, ride a camel into the Sahara, venture across 300-foot sand dunes, and spend the night under the stars, hours away from civilization. We didn't even need the [extra adjectives] for this one."_ (The other trips frequently use words like _beautiful_, _incredible_, _amazing_, etc.) I was looking for a commonly-known word to replace [extra adjectives]. Regardless, I learned a lot from this thread, so thank you, everyone who responded!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Words like those that have been stripped of semantic content and are used in a vain attempt to add emotion are usually called intensifiers.

> **intensifier**  a word, esp an adjective or adverb, that has little semantic content of its own but that serves to intensify the meaning of the word or phrase that it modifies.

[See this entry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=intensifier).

Comment: Is beautiful really an intensifier? AFAIK words like "very" or "most" are intensifiers

Comment: They become so through overuse and when merely used as filler.

Answer (score 4):

They're **Polar** predicates. They lie at the pole of a semantic cline, like *freezing* and *boiling*:

- ***freezing** - cold - cool - tepid - warm - hot - **boiling***

They're not the only ones, of course. The semantic test for them in English is use of ***absolute(ly)***, which is limited to use with polar predicates.

- *It's absolutely freezing in here.*
- **It's absolutely cold in here.*
- **It's absolutely cool in here.*
- **It's absolutely tepid in here.*
- **It's absolutely warm in here.*
- **It's absolutely hot in here.*
- *It's absolutely boiling in here.*

*Absolute(ly)* also distinguishes the polar 'crazy' sense of *mad* from its non-polar 'angry' sense.

- *He's mad about the horses.* (ambiguous: either 'angry' or 'crazy')
- *He's absolutely mad about the horses.* (unambiguous: 'crazy')

Thus, note the grammaticality of

- *absolutely beautiful*
- *absolutely incredible*
- *absolutely amazing*

and of course

- *Absolutely Fabulous.*

Answer (score 2):

When used to the extreme exaggeration, "Hyperbole" comes to mind:

> From the Wikipedia Dictionary:
>
> hy·per·bo·le (/hīˈpərbəlē/), Noun
>
> Exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally.
>   Synonyms: exaggeration - hyperbola - overstatement

---

> From the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary:
>
> Latin, from Greek
>   hyperbolē excess, hyperbole, hyperbola, from hyperballein to exceed,
>   from hyper- + ballein to throw First Known Use: 15th century

Answer (score 1):

The word I use most often is "[nondescript](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nondescript)". I use it with writers in discussing words that poorly describe their subjects, but it is generally a good description of your cohort of adjectives.

> nondescript (adj.):
>
> - belonging or appearing to belong to no particular class or kind : not easily described
> - lacking distinctive or interesting qualities

Answer (score 1):

If those words were about a person, it would be empty flattery. Maybe trite adjectives would serve for your purposes? I don't think there's a single word term to describe these words. Easier to come by are terms to describe the act of using overstated but meaningless adjectives and terms to label a person doing this. Depending on situation examples are: gloating, over-stating, being over-the-top, stupendifying (?), facecious, suck-up.